# decode a quoted printable message in php

Tags: php, encoding, quoted-printable

I have the string which that encoded in [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted_printable).  How do I decode this in php?

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vestibulum felis =
pede, vestibulum et, ullamcorper in, ultrices eget, metus. Suspendisse in n=
ulla. Sed justo. Donec dapibus auctor neque. Pellentesque faucibus ante nec=
 metus. Vivamus feugiat, velit rhoncus semper suscipit, libero augue venena=
tis leo, nec ornare nulla elit eget diam. Nullam sollicitudin.
```

Comment: Nice demonstration of where the syntax highlighting magic of this site falls flat on its belly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help: [quoted_printable_decode](https://www.php.net/quoted_printable_decode)

Comment: hrmph... I had tried this function.  Unfortunately a bug somewhere else led me to believe this function didn't work.  It works it my tests now though.