# Displaying HTML Emails Properly in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, email, imap

I'am working on an web email app with PHP. Currently I display every mail with a simple `imap_fetchbody` and HTMLPurifier on a Modal ,but I noticed that HTML Emails arent display correctly.

Here are two emails : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbTK6.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQGWE.jpg

Basiclly the CSS is kinda screwed up. And I need to way to display them as they should be.

If anyone has an idea I'd love to try it out.

Thanks in advance!

PS : If you need anything just comment.

Code (it's a bit messy ,sorry!):

```
<?php
require('get-imap-details.php');
session_start();
//require('database-logging.php');
require('htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
function DisplayEmails($email_address)
{
    //Open Imap with given credentials.
    //LogAllActions(); //Un-Command this line if you want to log all actions.
    $imap = OpenImap();
    $messages = imap_check($imap); //Load all messages that are in our catchall inbox
    $messages_displayed = 0; //Count of emails already displayed
    $max_messages_on_screen = 50; //Max messages you want to display at once, in this case 50
    $email_in_blacklist = false;
    $imap_result = imap_fetch_overview($imap,"1:{$messages->Nmsgs}",0);
    
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

    foreach(array_reverse($imap_result) as $email)
    {
        //Check if the email address isn't blacklisted, if it is, don't display anything.
        if(!BlacklistedEmailAddresses(explode('@',$email_address)[0]))
        {
            if($email->deleted !=1)
            {
                //Go through all emails, but display only emails for the current email address
                if($email->to == $email_address && $messages_displayed <= $max_messages_on_screen)
                {
            
            $messages_displayed += 1;
                    $message_id = $email->msgno;
                    $header = imap_header($imap, $message_id);
                    //The part of message we'll display as preview, you can change how many characters you want to display below.
            $characters_to_display = 50;         
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($imap , $message_id , 0);   
            $message_body = imap_body($imap , $message_id );
            $num = imap_num_msg($imap);
            $message_preview = substr(imap_fetchbody($imap, $message_id, 1), 0, $characters_to_display);
            $sender_address = $header->from[0]->mailbox."@".$header->from[0]->host;
            $date = $header->date;
            $mailtext = imap_fetchbody($imap , $message_id, 1 );
            //$clean_html = $purifier->purify($mailtext);
            $clean_html = $mailtext;

            $_SESSION['subject'] = $email->subject;
            $_SESSION['message'] = $clean_html;
             
         

                //Display all email as separate table raw.
                    //You can change this by chaning the echo below onto your own one               
                ?>  
                <tr>
<td scope="row"> <?php echo $sender_address; ?> </td><td> <?php echo $email->subject; ?></td><td><a href="#" style="color:#dc3545;" data-message=<?php //$message_body; ?> class="message" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal<?php echo $message_id ?>"><p> view message</p></a></td> <td><a href="#" style="color:#dc3545;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forwardModal<?php echo $message_id; ?>">forward Mail</a></td>

                </tr>




<!-- Message Modal -->
            <div id="addModal<?php echo $message_id; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width:960px;">
                        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#131516;color: rgb(188, 182, 173);">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                <h5> Details </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                             
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="coeg">
            <p>From :  <?php echo $sender_address; ?> </p>
            <p>Date :  <?php echo $header->date; ?> </p>
            <p>Title : <?php echo $email->subject; ?> </p>
            <hr>
            <p>Message :</p>
            <p id="message<?php echo $message_id; ?>">          </p>
            </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
        </div> 

<!-- Forwarding Modal -->


<div id="forwardModal<?php echo $message_id; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width:960px;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#131516;color: rgb(188, 182, 173);">
        <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>Forward Email</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Forward an email to your personal account if you want to save that email.</p>
                <hr>
            <form action="/assets/php/forward.php" method="post">
                <p>E-Mail address : <input type="email" name="forwarders_email"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" value="Forward E-Mail"></p>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>




<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- dataTables -->
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- loading-overlay -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@1.6.0/src/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
<script>        
//Message Modal Box      
$(function() {
   // $('#inbox').DataTable();
    $('body').on('click' , 'message', function() {
        var message = $(this).data('message');
    $('#coeg').html(message);
    document.getElementById("message<?php echo $message_id ?>").innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($clean_html); ?>;
    });
});
var msg = <?php echo json_encode($clean_html); ?>;
document.getElementById("message<?php echo $message_id ?>").innerHTML = msg; 


</script>     

<?php
}
                $email_timestamp = $email->udate;
                //Check for every email if it's older than 7 days. If it is, delete.
                //This is only used when the page is loaded by someone, if you want to automate this in cron jobs please check 'delete-old-emails.php'
                //You can change delete timeframe in 'get-imap-details.php'
                if(time()-GetDeleteTime() > $email_timestamp)
                {
                    imap_delete($imap, $email->msgno); //Mark message with specific id as 'for delete'
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $email_in_blacklist = true; //Email is in blacklist, don't display anything.
        }
    }
    //Display this content if there are no messages matching this email address
    if($messages_displayed == 0 && !$email_in_blacklist){
        echo "<tr><td><div style=\"color:grey;\">
  Nothing recieved yet. Click the Refresh Inbox button to reload your Email Inbox.
</div></td></tr>";
    }
    //Display if current email address is in blacklist, thus user can't access its content
    else if($email_in_blacklist){
        echo "<tr><th scope=\"row\">You can't view this email address</th></tr>";
    }
    //Delete all messages marked for delete, you can command the line below and keep them in your 'trash bin'
    imap_expunge($imap);
        imap_close($imap);

}
?>
```

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the CSS and HTML of the email in which "the CSS is kinda screwed up".

Comment: The second image looks like you didn't decode Quoted-Printable encoding on it, leaving. Lot of stray = in your html

Comment: Hey John Thanks for the answer. The HTML and CSS of the emails are the normal HTML emails meaning I don't change them or so. I just want to display them like e.g. Gmail would do. Here is a pastebin of the facebook mail : https://pastebin.com/Exx8MjRe

Comment: You may want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328590/decode-a-quoted-printable-message-in-php